# Is it safe to use the input() function as i am with my calculator?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi i am new to programming and i have been working on a calculator program. It is not finished yet, but my question today, is it dangerous to use the input() function as i have? I have done a lot of researching and i can find where it says to not use the input func with python 2 because it is dangerous and to use the raw_input but that module doesn't work how i need it to. Is there a safer way to do it. Here is my calculator code( its very basic and simple)

```
while True: 
  print '\nWhat do you want to multiply/divide/add/subtract ?', 
  calc = input(" ---> " )
  print '\nThe answer is %s\n' %(calc)
```

Also would I be able to add some code that if a anything other than a multiplication, addition, division, or subtraction problem is entered that it will say invalid input and continue similar to how this code works if anything other than 'y' or 'n' is entered? like this code below.(Sorry i couldn't add this in the title because it would have been to long.

```
while True:
    y = 'y'
    n = 'n'

    answer = raw_input('Run again? (y/n): ')
    if answer in ('y', 'n'):
        break
    print 'Invalid input.'

if answer == y:
    continue
else:
    print 'Goodbye'
    break
```

Thank you im sorry if this is a lot and i have tried researching and came close to figuring out how to add the invalid input, and i also need a way to quit the program by just typing quit.
~iMexa

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.x, `raw_input()` returns a string whereas `input()` evaluates the input in context. `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`. `input()` does not catch user errors. If the input is not valid, it simply raises a `SyntaxError`, unlike the `raw_input()` function.

Comment: Thank you i had tried doing this but i couldn't get it to work, maybe i typed it wrong before. But thank you that works. Is that safer than just input? And is there a way that if some types in something that will cause an error, it will say invalid input and start again instead of having to restart manually. Thanks again.

Comment: You can try using try and except blocks for ValueError. Convert your input to a specific data type, if it doesn't work, the code will move onto the except block.

Answer (score 0):

Python2 `input()` evaluates its content, while `raw_input()` returns it as a string.

```
# Python 2
input()
>>> 2+2
4

raw_input()
>>> 2+2
"2+2"
```

Not only will `input()` raise errors if used incorrectly, but it can also allow the program's user to perform unexpected operations, some of which can be dangerous.

Comment: Thank you that is what i have been finding, but is it safer to use the option of eval(raw_input(" ---> " ))   because i changed it to this and it works just as input() did. Thank you for replying.

Comment: @wyattwalden no, it is no safer, it is equivalent.

Comment: ok, what would be a better way to get the same out put then? With out using the input() function. Or is it ok in the sense i used it in? Thank you and i'm sorry i'm asking so much i'm just new.

Comment: It's impossible to tell without more of your code, but from what I understand it's most likely that your problems stem from your variables being strings instead of numbers. You can fix this problem by using `x = raw_input()` and then `x = int(x)` to change the variable's type to integer.